# Is it possible to justify SVG text using d3js?

Tags: d3.js, svg, text, justify, text-justify

I'm wrapping text using [M.Bostock's wrap function](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) but can't find a way to justify it.

Is that even possible in d3 ?
If not, is there a way to "mimic" this kind of text disposition ?

EDIT: Thanks to Logikos suggestion, i've found [this example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1424037) from M.Bostock putting a `foreignObject` inside `svg`.

Here is the snippet:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);
svg.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 480)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
    .html("<h1>An HTML Foreign Object in SVG</h1><p>Veeery long text");
```

Then you just need to add in the CSS:

```
body {text-align: justify;
     text-align-last: start;
}
```

Comment: Just a warning: `foreignObject` doesn't work on all browsers.

Comment: Also, I added "SVG" to the title: there is no such a thing as *"D3 text"*. The issue here is SVG, not D3.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado is correct however the support is not that bad, - http://caniuse.com/#search=foreignObject  for the most part except for opera mini it will work for what you want to do, if you reference the link I posted you will learn that there are some limitations however to filtering effects.

Comment: @Logikos It won't fork for any IE (11 and below). And (unfortunately) a lot of people use Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly what your looking for but something I used several years ago.  Instead of using that function to mimic wrapping you can instead put html inside svg with the foreignObject tag - http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg

As html you can style it however you want, text wrapping, justified etc etc.

I have not worked with d3 or SVG's in over 5 years so it is difficult to remember but thought I'd share this in-case it was of any use.

This is the example markup from the link I posted above:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150" fill="gray"/>
  <foreignobject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <div>Here is a <strong>paragraph</strong> that requires <em>word wrap</em></div>
    </body>

  </foreignobject>

  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="blue" stoke="red"/>
  <foreignobject x="120" y="120" width="180" height="180">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>First</strong> item</li>

          <li><em>Second</em> item</li>
          <li>Thrid item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
  </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

Please note browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=foreignObject
Which says it will work in everything other than opera mini.  Though there are some limitations in IE and Edge:

> 1 IE11 and below do not support . 2 IE and Edge do not
>   support applying SVG filter effects to HTML elements using CSS.

You should check it in IE and Edge, in one place the site says it does not support it, in another it says it supports it somewhat...

Comment: Thanks a lot Logikos. This solution is very useful and way simpler. I have edited my question.